# Stranger behaviour around the max value of int makes a query never answer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just noticed a stranger behavior on my SQL Server 2012. I have a table called BigTable that has a primary key `[id] [bigint] NOT NULL`, and when I do this :

```
select * from BigTable where id >= 2147460000 and id <= 2147490000
```

or

```
select top 1 * from BigTable where id >= 2147460000 and id <= 2147490000
```

It never answers (5min no answer) although there are records on that range. But when I choose other borders, for example between 2147470000 and 2147480000, it responds within a few ms.

I could not understand what was going on until I noticed that these values were around the Maximum value of an integer which is 2147483647. But still, I don't know why and I don't know how to make it work (respond quickly as it should). And by the way, this works fine:

```
select * from BigTable where id >= 2147490000 and id <= 2147500000
```

Can someone please explain to me what is going on?

Edit :

execution plan for the first query

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyeKQJ7is

execution plan for the second query query

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Byf37ymsi

Comment: Does `BigTable` have an index on `id`? Is it the clustered index? If not, does said index `INCLUDE` all the other columns in the table?

Comment: Compare execution plans (https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/). It's certainly possible some kind of implicit conversion step or cached previous execution is mucking things up; it could also be outdated histogram statistics leading to an incorrect cardinality estimate which in turn produces an inefficient plan that uses a scan rather than a seek. Only the execution plans will tell you.

Comment: @Larnu id is the primary key with clustered index. And for Include, even if I select only id, it never answers

Comment: `INCLUDE` doesn't reference the `SELECT`, @MehdiSouregi , it's related to an `INDEX`; specifically when you create a `NONCLUSTERED` index: `CREATE INDEX IX_SomeIndex ON dbo.SomeTable (SomeColumn) INCLUDE (AnotherColumn, SomeDate);` This means that the index includes details of the values of `AnotherColumn` and `SomeDate` but they are not part of the sort order.

Comment: @Larnu yes but in my case, this is a clustered Index since id is the primary key, and I rechecked, and the clustered Index is there. (And if I select only the id, it do not change the problem)

Comment: Yes, this is why the part about `INCLUDE` was in relation to if it *wasn't* the `CLUSTERED INDEX`. "If not [a `CLUSTERED INDEX`], does said index `INCLUDE` all the other columns in the table?" As it is, then posting the query plans will help us help you here.

Comment: @JeroenMostert you are right the execution plan for the two queries are different, but still don't know how to make the first query work, I will share the execution plan for both queries in a minute

Comment: Don't post images of execution plans please, use the link provided earlier by @JeroenMostert and post them to [Paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/).

Comment: What does `select top 1 * from BigTable where id >= CONVERT(BIGINT, 2147460000) and id <= CONVERT(BIGINT, 2147490000)` do?

Comment: @JeroenMostert it solves the problem :) the query responds quickly. Thank you!

Comment: The problem is that integer literals never implicitly become `BIGINT` -- instead `2147490000` is implicitly treated as a `DECIMAL(10, 0)`. It is still quite disappointing the engine fails to perform the `DECIMAL`-to-`BIGINT` conversion at the constant phase instead of inserting a range scan with mismatched types. If you use properly typed parameters here rather than constants, the problem of course does not arise, so this *shouldn't* be an issue in an actual application, as you are of course using parameterized queries rather than text replacement -- right? :P

Comment: I am using text replacement in a quick script I did this morning, so this will not be in the production I promise. Thank you for your clarified answer. :)